# Modify existing language translation

Tags: language-support, hebrew

I'm running Ubuntu 20.4, and I'm currently using Hebrew as my main language on my system. However, I would like to modify the existing translation, and fix some grammar issues with the language, and add some more lines to the language.
Is that possible?
if it is, how can I modify the language?
Thank you :)

(If I forgot to specify more details about my machine, please let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see a room for improvement, I would suggest that you get in touch with the Hebrew translators team and offer your help to improve it for everyone.

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-he](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-l10n-he)

(Changing some strings on your own machine only is possible, but actually harder than contributing to the real thing.)